# get one value two times with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have this code in jquery :

```
    $("#order_btn").click(function(){
        var totalprice = $(".price_amount").text();
        $("#totalprice").val(totalprice);
    });
```

When I submit this form with a hidden value i will get the totalprice value two times, if its 200000 i will get 200000200000. why ?

```
<input type="hidden" value="" name="totalprice" id="totalprice">
<input id="order_btn" type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
```

the price amout will defined here :

```
<span class="price_amount">75000</span>
```

I have this span tag two times, but I need both of them, is there a way to get one value only ?

Comment: are you sure that you have a single element with class `price_amount`? if so, why don't you use `id` instead of `class`?

Comment: yes two elements with same class name !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you most probably have more than one span tag with class "price_amount"

try using

```
var totalprice = $(".price_amount:first").text();
```

or

```
var totalprice = $(".price_amount:eq(0)").text();
// therefore you can access the second span tag like this
var totalprice = $(".price_amount:eq(1)").text();
// and so on...
```

if this makes it work, check your code for a superfluous span tag

EDIT:
should be right now

EDIT 2:
if your totalprice variable should be the sum of all you "price_amount" spans, consider following:

```
var totalprice = 0;
$.each($('.price_amount'),
      function()
      {
        totalprice += parseInt($(this).text());
      });
```

Comment: that's strange, you should be able to get the values of you "price_amount" span tags like that
try using   $(".price_amount").get()[0].text()

Comment: it should be `$(".price_amount:first").text()`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there's only one element on your page with the `price_amount` class? If you put a breakpoint (or an alert) on the value of `totalprice` after it's been assigned what do you get?

One other thing - and I'm not sure if this matters or not, but I would put this code in a handler for your form submit instead of click.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two `<span>` elements with the class "price_amount".

It's this line in particular

```
var totalprice = $(".price_amount").text();
```

When you call `.text()` from a jQuery set, it will aggregate that value for all selected nodes and return it.

So, either make sure you have only one span w/that classname, or make your selector more specific/granular so that you only retrieve the desired node.